# Multi-step functions with Observables in Angular 2 / Typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular

I am trying to follow a simple pattern in the Angular 2 docs, but am having difficulty executing a function.

The example I am working from is [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#promises) (app/toh/hero.service.ts (observable-based) file):

```
  getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  addHero (name: string): Observable<Hero> {
    let body = JSON.stringify({ name });
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(this.heroesUrl, body, options)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || { };
  }
  private handleError (error: any) {
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
```

I need to store a token after the `extractData` function, but do not think I'm calling it in right.  I get it to work when I put it in the `extraData` function, but I would like it to work on it's own:

```
 private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    if (body.response.user) {
      return this.storeToken;
    }
  }
  // want to call this function, but i'm doing something wrong
  private storeToken(res: Response ) {
    let resp = res;
    console.log("resp", resp);
    this.userId = resp.user.id;
    this.token = resp.user.authentication_token;
    localStorage.setItem('userId', this.userId);
    localStorage.setItem('token', this.token);
    return Rx.Observable.of('token', 'userId');
  }
  private handleError (error: any) {
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    return Rx.Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
```

I am not sure if any data is being passed into the `return this.storeToken` function, and I am not sure how to call it in the storeToken operator `(res: Response)`.

I feel this is extremely basic, but I have been hung up on it so any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

**Edit:**
This function works, but I would like to separate in two:

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    if (body.response.user) {
      this.userId = body.response.user.id;
      this.token = body.response.user.authentication_token;
      console.log("id:", this.userId);
      console.log("token:", this.token);
      localStorage.setItem('userId', this.userId);
      localStorage.setItem('token', this.token);
      return Rx.Observable.of('token', 'userId');
    }
  }
```

**Edit 2:**
Reading up on subscriptions and observables.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to be returning the invocation of the `.extractData` method rather than its signature?

**Instead of**

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    if (body.response.user) {
      return this.storeToken;
    }
  }
```

**Try this**

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    if (body.response.user) {
      return this.storeToken(res);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! 

Thought that would be the answer, but the console is saying `storeToken` is not a function -_-

Comment: Does it have something to with `res: Response`? What should I put if I wanted to do the body, `body: Object`? Was getting an error on that before as well :/

Comment: Actually, I think this issue is that the `map` is suppose to return what was converted. For example when you invoke `map` normally you can chain a `subscribe` and that gives you the object that was mapped, not an `observable`.

Comment: Ahh ok i see. That makes sense